# Interval Subtraction

Tags: scheme, sicp, interval

From the Extended Exercise beginning in section [2.1.4](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-14.html), you can find exercise 2.8:

> Exercise 2.8.  Using reasoning
>   analogous to Alyssa's, describe how
>   the difference of two intervals may be
>   computed. Define a corresponding
>   subtraction procedure, called
>   sub-interval.

I wrote the following:

```
(define (sub-interval x y)
  (make-interval (- (lower-bound x) (upper-bound y))
                 (- (upper-bound x) (lower-bound y))))
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks great.  Don't forget to define `lower-bound` and `upper-bound` as `car` and `cdr` respectively.